# How to convert a string of 10 digits to 5 bytes containing the input string as hex values in Python

Tags: python

my_string = "0123456789".

I want to convert this string to 5 bytes containing the input string as hex values(each byte representing two digits). Wanted output may be something like

```
byte1 = 0x01
byte2 = 0x23
byte3 = 0x45
byte4 = 0x67
byte5 = 0x89
```

All the smart people, please share your opinion or a sample code.

Comment: Do you actually want strings, bytes or integers as output? As shown, your desired output are  the *integers* 1, 35, 69, 103 and 137.

Answer (score 0):

Method [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) does exactly that:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('0123456789')
b'\x01#Eg\x89'

>>> [hex(i) for i in bytes.fromhex('0123456789')]
['0x1', '0x23', '0x45', '0x67', '0x89']
```